# How to calculate power dissipation of LDMOS-device for arbitrary waveforms

Tags: power-amplifier, class-d

I am currently simulating a current mode class D PA and would like calculate the dissipated power in the LDMOS-transistors I am using. I am currently doing this by calculating the RMS value of both the drain current and the DS-voltage and then multiplying these values together. However, calculating the RMS value does not take into account the phase between the two signals, so I think this procedure can't be quite right.

Edit: I am doing a transient simulation in a simulator called QucsStudio. A pwm-modulated sine with a signal frequency of 1 MHz and a modulation frequency of 100 MHz is used, the fixed step size for the simulation is 1e-10.

Is it possible to calculate a useful power dissipation value using the numerical signals output by the simulation? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *How do I calculate this the right way?*

There's not enough information in your question to decide if there's a trick or simplification that can be used so, in the absence of any circuit or other information, you are left with taking the average of [*instantaneous voltage multiplied by instantaneous current*].

You also need to respect the speed of the signal and take enough samples to avoid aliasing.

Alternatively, you could use a simulator to get a decent handle on what the power dissipation is.

At the end of the day it boils down to to the good old tried and tested formula: \$v\times i\$.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I added some information about simulation and input signal and updated my question. Would the averaged instantaneous power be a good approximation to the actual power loss per transistor?

Comment: The averaged instantaneous power will be *the* actual power loss.

Comment: Alright, I got a bit confused there for a moment. Thanks a lot!